# How can I unlock single-user mode?

Tags: password, recovery, safe-mode

I stupidly forgot the password to my MacbookPro. I have locked single user mode 2 weeks ago (for security reasons). How can I unlock single-user mode to get my password back?

Thanks guys :D

Comment: By locked you are referring to Open Firmware Password ? If so you can bypass it this way : http://osxdaily.com/2009/10/19/bypass-mac-firmware-password/

Comment: Yup, I have checked the article already, but I cannot open my mac! I had enough accidents with it already (it dropped on the floor) :(

Comment: The only way to bypass an Open firmware password is by changing physical components. It would be very difficult to bypass the OFP without having physical access...

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to geting if you follow this link to the [Apple website](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1274) where you will find information on resetting the administrators account password.

You will require a Mac OS install disc as close to the OS you are using as possible